# Dynamic Layout not work properly

Tags: android, layout, dynamic

I have a problem while creating the dynamic layouts in Android. I can't get any output while testing the code, although I provide background color, it shows blank on the device. I have used weight according to `JSON` size, which was initially 3, and want to create blocks accordingly.

**XML layout**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="9.5"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="0.5"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="9"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

          <ScrollView
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

              <LinearLayout
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:id="@+id/mainlinear"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
              </LinearLayout>
          </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

**java code**

```
public class offers extends Activity {
    int len;
    String offerjson;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.offers);

        offerjson = getIntent().getExtras().getString("offersjson");

        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(offerjson);
            len = jsonArray.length();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        final LinearLayout lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlinear);
        lm.setWeightSum(len);

        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(offerjson);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject job = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                //////////////////////////////// outer Layout
                LinearLayout l0 = new LinearLayout(offers.this);
                l0.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0, 1.0f));
                l0.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black_border));
                l0.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                l0.setWeightSum(4);

                ////////////////////////////////////inner 1 layout
                LinearLayout l1 = new LinearLayout(offers.this);
                l1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0, 1.0f));
                l1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFE7E7E7"));
                l1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                l0.addView(l1);
                ///////////////////////////////Inner 2 LLayout
                LinearLayout l2 = new LinearLayout(offers.this);
                l2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0, 2.0f));
                l2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                l0.addView(l2);
                /////////////////////////Inner 3 LLayout
                LinearLayout l3 = new LinearLayout(offers.this);
                l3.setLayoutParams(new   LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0, 0.9f));
                l3.setWeightSum(4);
                l3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                l3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFABABA"));

                l0.addView(l3);

                //////////////////////////////////////

                LinearLayout l4 = new LinearLayout(offers.this);
                l4.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0, 0.1f));

                l4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF52caf7"));
                l4.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                l0.addView(l4);
                lm.addView(l0);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: basically i want a dynamic linear layout which repeat itself according to json data ,which contain 3 linear layouts inside it vertically ( where i will put my data). Please help me sugggesting how to do?

Comment: I also want to know which class to import while using LayoutParams as it asks like class to import :android.widget.Gridlayout.LayoutParams,android.widget.ViewGroup.LayoutParams, android.widget.Relative.LayoutParams  etc

Comment: why are you using a weight of 9.5 on the root layout? Why not match_parent in stead?

Comment: root element is inside another layout .I have pasted only useful info.

Comment: i have done half of it. the only issue persists is that the last LinearLayout which is vertical is not visible when i use weight and make its width 0 otherwise it is visible.

Comment: Go read up on RecyclerViews. You're building your own type of ListView here which is not going to work out. Also go read this page. http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html. You cant nest LinearLayouts like that it will kill your device if there's a lot of items in the JSONArray.

Comment: thanks I will work on it, bu now i am in hurry so i'll be thankful if someone provides me a dynamic code containing 3 linear layouts inside 1 using weight